# Send value from backend to frontend in Sails.js and check with EJS

Tags: javascript, sails.js, frontend, backend, ejs

I'm trying to submit data from a form, then from the controller there are 3 possibilities, it already exists, the data is wrong and it was successfully created. Then I want to return a value to the front-end, let's say everything is ok and I return {result: 0}.
Then using ejs I'll check the value of 'result' and if it's a 0 I want to call a (front-end) javascript function.

**EJS:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="functions.js">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/test" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="data" />
      <button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <div id="message">
      <% if (typeof result !== 'undefined' && result === 0){ %><script>showMessage();</script><% } %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript** (front-end)

```
function showMessage() {
  document.getElementById('message').innerText = "sometext";
}
```

**Javascript** (back-end)

```
module.exports = {
  postData: function (req, res) {
    Data.findOne({data: req.param('data')}).exec(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return {result : 1};
      }
      if (data) {
        return {result: 2};
      }
      if (!data) {
        Data.create({data: req.param('data')}, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            return {result: 1};
          }
          return {result: 0};
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I know how to send data using res.view(), but I don't want to reload the page again I just want to send something to the frontend and make some action.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Understand server-side and client-side rendering. You may use AJAX for your use case. Most likely, you are using EJS for server side rendering hence you can not use EJS on frontend (to check return value).

Comment: You're right. I'm using EJS server-side to render something to the client.

What I'm using currently is "return res.view('test', {result: 0});" which does work, I can check result value then using EJS, but it reloads the page again and that disturbs the experience.

Would it be possible to use some function (with EJS) that did what the sails.js controller is doing (check the DB and all that)? Wouldn't it be insecure?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to include the Javascript script you want to execute inline. Then, you can use a conditional EJS clause to include your script if the result is equal to 0.

```
<% if (result == 0) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Your Function Here */ 
    </script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I already have that, the problem is that I only know one way to send data from the controller and that is using res.view() and I don't want that.

Comment: You can return data from the controller using res.json(), in which case, you need to look into implementing an API.

Answer (score 0):

You can store variables in the backend eg. `someVariable = "some value"`

Then in your frontend call `<%- someVariable %>`

OR save it as an object in the backend eg.

```
vehicle.car = {
    manufacturer: 'Holden',
    make: 'Colorado',
    year: '2018'
}
```

THEN in the frontend call the object model eg.

```
<p>Your <%- vehicle.car.year %> <%- vehicle.car.manufacturer %> <%- vehicle.car.make %>...
```

A use case example is to show the current year of copyright of a footer [partial](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/views/partials%22partial%22) that persist page requests.